# How to set vm arguments in build.xml for JFX default On Screen Keyboard?

Tags: javafx

I have a kiosk application built in Java Fx. How to set following VM Options in build.xml(ant script) of my application (.Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx) ? If anyone has done something similiar to this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`<fx:jvmarg>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIAHJIJG) for specifying any JVM argument.

It is to be used inside its parent [`<fx:platform>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIAEEFCJ).

An example on how to use it is

```
<fx:platform javafx="8.0+">
    <fx:jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=true"/>
    <fx:jvmarg value="-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=javafx"/>
</fx:platform>
```

Similar examples can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference.htm#CIAGFFIF).